# Google Colab Roll Back

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory

Some Keras Package of my old code , Of Sept 2023 stopped working in Nov 6 2023.
I am not remembering what all were those package by default by then.

Is there any way I can have the Google Colab roll back to a previous veriosn.

Below is the Error Message from my current code while complied a couple of months before.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-1c3947b2993d> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 import numbers
      2 from datetime import datetime
----> 3 from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten,GaussianDropout
      4 from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
      5 #from keras.optimizers import SGD

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/callbacks.py in <module>
     13 from collections import deque
     14 from collections import OrderedDict
---> 15 from collections import Iterable
     16 from .utils.generic_utils import Progbar
     17 from . import backend as K

ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterable' from 'collections' (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the python [version 10](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#removed) has removed this class:

> Remove deprecated aliases to Collections Abstract Base Classes from the collections module. (Contributed by Victor Stinner in bpo-37324.)

You can try to downgrade your python version to 9 for compatibility by running this command to a cell(Save your notebook first just to be safe):

```
!sudo apt-get install python3.9
```

Check the version after installation

!python --version